# AzCopy authenticate: Selected user account does not exist in tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I need to download a blob from my blob storage. I am trying to authenticate my user identity as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

```
azcopy login
```

When I follow the directions, and enter the provided code into the webform, I'm told:

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services'
> and cannot access the application
> '<>' in that tenant. The account
> needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use
> a different account.

I am using my main admin Azure account user (owner), which is the only one I've set up.

I have obviously tried to Google this and looked at the directions and looked at other question/answers. It's a freaking rabbit hole of links to page with more links. **Please, where do I click, what do I type**, to create this user that I need, or how do I give my admin user whatever it needs?

I looked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant for how to create a tenant, but one of the steps is to type in the domain. What domain? Do I need a domain to download a blob?

I also thought that maybe I need to provide a tenant id:

```
azcopy login --tenant-id=<tenant-id>
```

But where do I find a tenant ID? I figured out that this is apparently the same as the directory id.

I tried to do:

My storage account > Properties

but there is nothing here called tenant or directory id.

Comment: `Search resources > tenant properties > tenantID`  Do you have access to that route from `portal.azure.com`?

Comment: You're right that the issue was the lack o tenant-id, but I couldn't find it this way. Wrote an answer for what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue wasn't related to the user, but that I needed to provide a tenant id

```
azcopy login --tenant-id=<tenant-id>
```

To get the tenant-id:

In the Azure portal dashboard:

- Search Azure Active Directory
- Choose Azure Active Directory
- Copy the Tenant ID